# Не удается сохранить json через gson

Tags: java, android, json, файлы, gson

Не удается сохранить класс в json, через gson. Нужный файл создается, но он полностью пустой, а если я получаю структуру файла через  `String str = gson.toJson(itemList);` То он выводит нужную мне структуру как надо.

Вот метод сохранения:

```
public boolean Save(itemList itemList)
{
    boolean result = false;
    try
    {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        File sdPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        switch (itemList.Tag)
        {
            case "orph":
                sdPath = new File(sdPath.getAbsolutePath() + resources.getString(R.string.path_orph) + "/" + itemList.id);
                break;
            case "arif":
                sdPath = new File(sdPath.getAbsolutePath() + resources.getString(R.string.path_arif) + "/" + itemList.id);
                break;
        }
        gson.toJson(itemList, new FileWriter(sdPath.getPath()));

        String str = gson.toJson(itemList);

        Log.d("myLog", str + " gsonRes");

        result = true;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Вот сам `itemList` :

```
public class itemList implements Parcelable
{
    public String nameList;
    public String Tag;
    public ArrayList<itemQuestion> itemQuestions;
    public int id;

    public itemList(String nameList, String Tag, ArrayList<itemQuestion> itemQuestions, int id)
    {
        this.nameList = nameList;
        this.Tag = Tag;
        this.itemQuestions = itemQuestions;
        this.id = id;
    }

    protected itemList(Parcel in) {
        nameList = in.readString();
        Tag = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<itemList> CREATOR = new Creator<itemList>() {
        @Override
        public itemList createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new itemList(in);
        }

        @Override
        public itemList[] newArray(int size) {
            return new itemList[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(nameList);
        dest.writeString(Tag);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Преобразуйте json строку в модель следующим образом:

```
gson.fromJson(decode(jsonString), itemList.class);
```

Comment: Спасибо 1234567